# Converting Char array to int/double/float

Tags: c

Thx for the help but maybe I should clarify my problem.  I want to read some addresses from a text file, for instance:

someFile::
0xc4fap4424ab1 0xac8374ce93ac ... etc

Now I want to take these addresses and convert them to decimal so that I can make address comparisons.  So my question is 
1.  How should I go about storing these addresses
2.  Once I have stored the addresses, how can I convert them to decimal.

Comment: That doesn't even compile. What are you *really* trying to do ?

Comment: Is that supposed to be: `"0xfffffffffff0"`?

Comment: when did 'p' become a hex digit?

Comment: Sorry typo there, anyways just assume those are correct hex num.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your initializer declares just one element for the `temp` array, and that value is way beyond the capacity of a `char`. The maximum value that you can store in a single `char` is `0xFF`.

If `temp` was something in the form of:

```
char temp[] = {0x12, 0x34, 0x56, 0x78};
```

Then you could do some bit twiddling to produce an `int` out of the 4 bytes. Actually I would use `uint32_t` to be platform-independent:

```
uint32_t x = (temp[0] << 24) | (temp[1] << 16) | (temp[2] << 8) | temp[3];
```

Of course, you have to take care of the endianness as well.

Comment: Thx for the help but maybe I should clarify my problem.  I want to read some addresses from a text file, for instance:

someFile::
0xc4fap4424ab1 0xac8374ce93ac ... etc